# Visited questions on main are indistinguishable from unvisited ones

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Quick, tell me which of these questions I've clicked on:

[image: screen shot - main]

That screen shot was taken in Safari, a browser in which I have done zero customization.  (I keep it around just for tests like this.)  I see the same thing in Chrome.

On meta, on the other hand, there's a difference (this one is from Chrome):

[image: screen shot - meta]

Could we get some better differentiation between visited and unvisited links on the front page of main?  I try to read most of the questions, so I want the ones I've haven't read to stand out.

Comment: Yup, this is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just pushed an update. This should be resolved now. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!  That fixed it.